# .htaccess add trailing slash on pages except when #'s are in the URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, expressionengine

I want my URL's to add the trailing slash, but only when the URL does not end with an anchor.

Here's my current .htaccess file

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Enable Rewrite Engine
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Remove the www from the URL
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Add a trailing slash to paths without an extension
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]


# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Remove index.php
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

**When I link to an anchor'd section, the URL's get written to:**

```
http://mysite.com/subdir/#anchor
```

**When they should look like this:**

```
http://mysite.com/subdir#anchor
```

**Regular URLs should look like this:**

```
http://mysite.com/directory/sub/
```

I'm pretty stumped, so any help would be great!

Cheers, 
Dan

Answer (score 3):

Don't think the issue with that are because of your Rewrite rules. Fragments (the `#something` at the end of a URI) don't ever get sent to the server, they're used as a subordinate resource inside the page that is being rendered by the browser.

Make sure the HTML that you are serving doesn't contain trailing slashes in your anchors, or that you don't have javascript that appends them on the browser's side.

---

EDIT:

Well, if it's a matter of removing the added slash at the end of your URI, you probably want to comment out this rule:

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Add a trailing slash to paths without an extension
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Ah right, at the very very end of the URI the slash doesn't get added (I updated my post). However, the slash is still added before the the # sign.

Comment: my bad, I updated my post yet again to say that I want my URLs to add the trailing slash but only when the URL doesn't end with a #

Comment: @Dan You can't do that, at least not with htaccess and mod_rewrite. Apache doesn't know when URL's end with a "#" or not. The URI fragments are strictly for the browser.

Comment: Works like a charm for me. Thanks @JonLin!

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at Apache's [Directory Slash](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) setting?

Here's what we are using in .htaccess to handle a similar problem

```
DirectorySlash Off
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
```

Comment: didn't seem to do the trick, ill keep this in mind for the future though